# Instalar mi propio proyecto de Github

Tags: php, github

Yo estoy construyendo [mi propia clase en Github](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO) para manejar las conexiones y consultas a la base de datos en un servidor remoto.

Yo tengo copiados mis archivos directamente en las carpetas del servidor y funcionan perfecto, pero quiero saber cuáles serían los pasos para instalar de forma automática los archivos de ese proyecto en mi servidor.

La idea es mantenerlos **actualizados**, de forma que cuando modifique algo en Github mis archivos se actualicen en el servidor.

¿Hay alguna forma de instalar los archivos de ese proyecto desde Github en mi servidor mediante `composer` u otros? ¿Cuáles serían los pasos a dar para ello? ¿Cuando modifique un archivo en Github éste se actualizaría en el servidor?

Answer (score 5):

GitHub tiene una funcionalidad llamada WebHooks, la cual te permite configurarla para que GitHub te envíe una notificación cada que sucede un evento determinado en tu repositorio.
La forma en la que GitHub te avisa es por medio de una llamada POST a un servidor que tu tienes que crear.

Para crear un nuevo webhook ve a la pestaña 'Settings' en tu repositorio

[image: opciones de un repositorio]

y bajo la opción de 'Webhooks' puedes crear uno nuevo que te avise cada que se hace un 'push' a tu repositorio

[image: vista webhooks GitHub]

Ya que configuraste tu webhook, tienes que crear un pequeño servidor que pueda recibir la llamada de GitHub donde tienes instalada tu aplicación, y que al recibir la llamada haga un 'git pull' y los pasos necesarios para actualizar tu servidor a la nueva versión.